# How to control the filter size

Tags: c++, filter

This is my first learn with Filter. I had a problem when I learning the C ++ filter.I got an exmaple code about filter, but the output of this filter was too big, because I wanted the filter can less than 1KB in size. I want to add a for loop so that I can add only the appropriate size of content to the filter, but I'm having some problem with this process.

This is my filter code:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        ifstream filter_file(argv[1]);
        set<string> filter_lines;
        string line;
        for (string line; getline(filter_file, line);)
        {
            bitset<256> control_size;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < control_size.size(); ++i)
            {
                filter_lines.insert(line);
            }
        }
        for (string line; getline(cin, line); ) {
            if (filter_lines.find(line) != filter_lines.end()) {
                cout << line << endl;
            }
        }
        if (!cin.eof()) {
            throw runtime_error("Error reading from std::cin.");
        }
    }
}
```

But my for loop doesn't seem to be able to limit it successfully. It is my understanding that getline is used to get the entire file, and then for loop controls the size. Is there something wrong with my understanding? How do I modify it?

Comment: "doesn't seem" is also not a good description. Further, you should extract a [mcve] and provide that here, along with expected and actual observations. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Concerning `filter_lines.insert(line);`: A `std::set` is an associative array. Inserting the same value multiple times is useless because a `std::set` doesn't store duplicates. Concerning `bitset<256> control_size;` and `for (size_t i = 0; i < control_size.size(); ++i)`: You don't do anything with `control_size` accept using its size. A `size_t n = 256` would have worked as well, wouldn't it? But, actually, inserting the same value multiple times into a `std::set`... Sorry, I already mentioned it. ;-)

Comment: getline returns a reference to the input stream and when a stream is converted to a bool the result will only be false if any of the fail bits are set, not at end-of-stream.